# How to debug Kmeans clusters on python 3.9 tensorflow on Mac M1 pro?

Tags: tensorflow, k-means, python-3.9

When you installed python 3.9 tensorflow on new Mac M1 chip, you would probably come to this bug when you run `Kmeans.predict()`:

```
nonetype' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have searched online for a long time but cannot find any useful solution. So if you happen to have the same issue as mine, maybe you can try this:

1. Find the file threadpoolctl.py under /Users/YOURNAME/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages
2. Replace it by the file in this website:
   https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl/blob/master/threadpoolctl.py
3. Restart your python

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

+100500 to the karma: worked for me as well within Python 3.8. The version of threadpoolctl.py was "2.1.0" - after making an update by version "3.2.0.dev0" KMeans started to work.